# Action "apache2ctl graceful" failed | Let's Encrypt on Raspbian with Owncloud

Tags: apache, ssl, raspberry-pi, apache2, lets-encrypt

Currently I've got the problem that I can't install an SSL Certificate on my locale RPI-4B with Owncloud installed on it.

I tried installing the Certificate using this (German) Tutorial: [Click here](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/raspberry-pi-ssl-zertifikat-kostenlos-mit-lets-encrypt-erstellen/)

But everytime I tip in: `sudo letsencrypt -d srvschneg.ddns.net --redirect -m {MY MAIL}`, the following error is thrown

```
What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate
2: Renew & replace the cert (limit ~5 per 7 days)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 1
Keeping the existing certificate
Deploying Certificate to VirtualHost /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.


Unable to restart apache using ['apache2ctl', 'graceful']
Rolling back to previous server configuration...
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.


Unable to restart apache using ['apache2ctl', 'graceful']
Encountered exception during recovery:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2185, in _reload
    util.run_script(self.option("restart_cmd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/util.py", line 86, in run_script
    raise errors.SubprocessError(msg)
certbot.errors.SubprocessError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 526, in deploy_certificate
    self.installer.restart()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2175, in restart
    self._reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2203, in _reload
    raise errors.MisconfigurationError(error)
certbot.errors.MisconfigurationError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2185, in _reload
    util.run_script(self.option("restart_cmd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/util.py", line 86, in run_script
    raise errors.SubprocessError(msg)
certbot.errors.SubprocessError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/error_handler.py", line 108, in _call_registered
    self.funcs[-1]()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 626, in _rollback_and_restart
    self.installer.restart()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2175, in restart
    self._reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot_apache/configurator.py", line 2203, in _reload
    raise errors.MisconfigurationError(error)
certbot.errors.MisconfigurationError: Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.


Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I already tried it lots of times -> I really don't know anymore what I should do...

I hope anyone is able to help me
Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I finally made it using those 3 lines in the default-ssl.conf:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydom.tld/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydom.tld/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateFile       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydom.tld/cert.pem
```

https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/installation/letsencrypt/apache.html#create-an-ssl-virtualhost-configuration